# How to combine two environment variable in @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have application.yaml as following

```
environment: ${ZK_ENVIRONMENT}
END_POINT_URL:
  dev: http://sampledev.uk.com
  qa: http://sampleqa.uk.com
  prod: http://sampleprod.uk.com
```

environment values can be dev,qa or prod. I need o inject END_POINT_URL based on environment in @Value.Tried the following, it's not working.

```
@Value("${END_POINT_URL}.${environment}")
private String url;
```

Comment: Don't - use profiles or set variables with startup params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, just did a quick test as well

`@Value("${END_POINT_URL.${environment}}")`

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    
    @Value("${END_POINT_URL.${environment}}")
    private String value;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

ZK_ENVIRONMENT:dev
Output : http://sampledev.uk.com